# `flutterWebviewPlugin` cover the drawer, it is possible to change the zIndex?

Tags: dart, flutter, drawer

I am using Flutter to develop a webview with menu, and the menu will trigger the drawer, but the `flutterWebviewPlugin` draw the UI on top of everything, that's cover the drawer as well, is this possible to move the drawer upper or let the webview put lower? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the package description

> **Warning:** The webview is not integrated in the widget tree, it is a
>   native view on top of the flutter view. you won't be able to use
>   snackbars, dialogs...

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin

Answer (score 0):

Use [fluter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) as it have much better features than official and other plugins.